# Are these two summation expressions equal to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

Is this equality true?

$$n!\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1^k + (-1)^k}{2(\frac{k}{2}!)} \right).\left( \frac{1}{(n-k)!} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{(2k)!}{k!}.\binom{n}{2k}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the left side is nonzero only when $k$ is even, let $k=2j$ to get

$\displaystyle n!\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1^k + (-1)^k}{2(\frac{k}{2}!)} \right).\left( \frac{1}{(n-k)!} \right)=n!\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{j!}\cdot\frac{1}{(n-2j)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{n!}{j!(n-2j)!}$

$\displaystyle=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{(2j)!}{j!}\cdot\frac{n!}{(2j)!(n-2j)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{(2j)!}{j!}\binom{n}{2j}$

Answer (score 1):

On the right you have $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \frac {n!}{k!(n-2k)!}$.

On the left, notice that $\frac{1^k + (-1)^k}{2}$ is 1 when $k$ is even and 0 when $k$ is odd. Changing indexes carefully gives the equality.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `"changing indexes carefully"`?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on justt's answer, note that the LHS is 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2} {n \choose k} \frac{k!}{(k/2)!}.
$$
[Also, what do you mean by $(3/2)!$, ($k=3$)?]

Comment: $(3/2)!$ wouldn't occur because $\frac{1^k + (-1)^k}{2}$ is 0 when $k$ is odd, as stated by justt.

Comment: I understand that there is a factor which is zero, but having undefined terms isn't exactly kosher.

Comment: I coun't find a way to write without using $(k/2)!$. This is derived from $n!\sum_{k=0}^n\left([z^k](\frac{z^0}{0!} + \frac{z^2}{1!} + \frac{z^4}{2!} + \frac{z^6}{3!} ...) . [z^{n-k}](\frac{z^0}{0!} + \frac{z^1}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + ...)\right)$